# phonegap / jquery mobile - iframe &the back button

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm working on a Phonegap/jQuery Mobile Android app.

A particular piece of content involves displaying a page which is on our server.  We have used an IFrame to display this, all works fine apart from the back button.  If you click through a couple of pages within the IFrame and press the phone's back button the app goes back a page rather than the content within the iframe, which is an issue.

I'm guessing it would be really tricky to get around this, but does anyone have ideas or alternate methods of displaying a external site with back button use?

Comment: http://denrobapps.com/2010/12/phonegap-and-iframes/

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to override the default onBack method, and provide your own.
You need to figure out how to simulate going back within the iFrame programmatically